# How to get size of previous siblings of current element in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am a bit stuck with the following JQuery problem:

I have the following structure:

```
<ul>
<li id="one">one</li>
<li id="two">two</li>
<li id="three">three</li>
<li id="four">four</li>
<li id="five">five</li>
</ul>
```

I want my code to select #three, and get the total size of the ul up to that element. So it would need to get the total size (including margins, paddings and borders) of #one and #two.

What's the most effective way of doing this?

UPDATE:

This is the final code I used, thanks to @Pointy suggestion. The code is used to position nested ul submenus, inside each li of a horizontal ul menu at the beggining of the parent ul.

```
$("#menu-headermenu-1 > li.menu-item" ).each(function (index) {
    var $leftWidth = ($(this).offset().left - $(this).closest('ul').offset().left);     
    $leftWidth = ($leftWidth * -1) ;
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').css('left', $leftWidth);
  });
```

Comment: Do you mean "size" in just one dimension (vertical), or two dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the vertical "size", you could just diff the offset top of the `<li>` "three" and the `<ul>` itself.

```
var $three = $('#three'), sz = $three.offset().top - $three.closest('ul').offset().top;
```

Comment: actually, I just need the horizontal size, I forgot to mention it.  I was trying to use prevAll(), but this looks easier. I am going to try it now

Comment: It worked! Much easier. I will copy my final code in my post in case somebody needs it. Thanks Pointy.